# Does the Netherlands tax citizen's wealth?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, wealth-tax

[This question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/91432/how-to-best-invest-90-000-eur-with-zero-knowledge-in-investing) implies that the Netherlands government taxes citizens' wealth year after year; even well beyond it originally being earned by the citizen. Is that true?

Comment: The tax [linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_tax_in_the_Netherlands#Flat_tax_on_savings_and_investments_(box_3)) in the comment is only 1.2% of the current value in the bank.  It's not "beyond originally being earned by the citizen".

Comment: I earned it yesterday when I received my paycheck and it looks as though it is taxed every single year after that point. So yeah - well beyond the point when I earned it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Netherlands has what is known as the ["Box 3" tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_tax_in_the_Netherlands) that is somewhat like a tax on net wealth. Net assets are treated as if they yield 4% and are then taxed at 30%. This results in a effective tax rate of 1.2% on net assets.

This [page from KPMG](https://home.kpmg.com/xx/en/home/insights/2011/12/Netherlands-income-tax.html) delves further into Box 3 taxation:

> Box 3 deals with capital income, that is, income from savings and
>   investments. Taxable income is determined on the basis of a deemed
>   return on capital. This deemed return is a percentage of the total
>   value of assets and liabilities on 1 January of the tax year. The
>   deemed percentage is applied after deduction of an exempt amount (EUR
>   30.000 per taxpayer). It is emphasized that the taxable income is computed without regard to the actual income received. Thus, if actual
>   income exceeds the deemed percentage, no tax is due on the excess.
>   Conversely, there is no reduction in tax if actual income is less than
>   the deemed percentage. The deemed income is taxed at 30 percent. For
>   these purposes, assets include not only money, shares, bonds, and
>   tangible assets (such as a second house) but also any intangible
>   assets, which have an economic value. The latter could include, for
>   example, permits, licenses, and patents. Non-qualifying annuities are
>   taxed in Box 3. Depending on the circumstances, rights arising under
>   trusts may be covered by Box 3.

Comment: I heard "yes-ish". I guess if you live in the Netherlands you'd either better literally store your money as cash in a mattress or invest it at a hopefully > 4% rate of return.

Comment: @DeepDeadpool I think even cash in a mattress counts as an asset. And if you're earning less than 1.2% on your assets, you're being taxed at over 100% of your actual capital gains.

Comment: I think you're right about the asset classification

Comment: @DeepDeadpool: EUR 500 exception for cash. That's 6 euro saved.

Comment: It's like a second property tax...but on all your assets...

Comment: Interesting-- do they also charge capital gains when you sell your assets? If you're not being taxed twice this might actually be a lower rate of taxation than the US.

Comment: @Dugan: No capital gains tax, unless you trade professionally. (in which case gains are simply taxed as regular income, there's no special rule for capital gains)

Comment: @Dugan: the NL tax regime can be better for short term holdings, where the higher capital gains rate is used. For typical rates of return on assets, the  difference could be 1-2%. For truly long-term holdings (10+ years), it's another story: the drag of a 1.2% lower rate of return every year starts to dominate. After 30 years of compounding, this can easily add up to 15-25% less capital under the NL system. (And under a recent proposal to change the box 3 tax, this difference will become even greater.)

Answer (score 5):

I think you will find that the Netherlands doesn’t tax citizens but residents. I think the USA is the only country that taxes its citizens even when they haven’t been in the USA for many years.

Comment: It can be offset by a foreign tax credit, but yeah, pretty unique...